# Windows Phone countdown app

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to do two things:

On Christmas day, invoke a method whenever the page is navigated to.

After Christmas day, set the christmasDay DateTime to +1 year (so the countdown "resets").

Here is my code:

```
 private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime christmasDay;
            DateTime.TryParse("11/17/13", out christmasDay);
            var timeLeft = christmasDay - DateTime.Now;


            int x = DateTime.Now.Year - christmasDay.Year;
            if (DateTime.Now > christmasDay)
            {
                if (x == 0)
                    x += 1;
                christmasDay.AddYears(x);
                if (DateTime.Now.Month == christmasDay.Month && DateTime.Now.Day == christmasDay.Day)
                {
                    itsChristmas();
                }
            }

             countdownText.Text = String.Format("{0:D2} : {1:D2} : {2:D2} : {3:D2}", timeLeft.Days, timeLeft.Hours, timeLeft.Minutes, timeLeft.Seconds);
        }
```

When I set the date to TODAY, the "itsChristmas()" method works...but I don't actually want it to be invoked on each tick of the countdown. I tried putting it in the constructor of the page but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

The second problem is that if I set the date to a day before today, it gives me negative numbers. I don't know what is wrong with my code that this is happening. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is quite complex. You could solve it like this.

```
private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var christmasDay = NextChristmas();

    if (now.Date < christmasDay.Date)
    {
        // it's not christmas yet, nothing happens
    }

    if (now.Date == christmasDay.Date)
    {
        // it's christmas, do your thing
        itsChristmas();
    }
}

private DateTime NextChristmas()
{
    var thisYearsChristmas = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 25);

    if (DateTime.Now.Date <= thisYearsChristmas.Date) return thisYearsChristmas;
    return thisYearsChristmas.AddYears(1);
}
```

The `if` statemements can be written more consise but I elaborated on them to make clear what happens.

Comment: Well I switched to my above code thinking that I could make it work without using isolated storage because I can't figure out how to save a DateTime into isolated storage. :( (I'm very new to this.)